# Google OAuth2: Exchange access code for Refresh and Bearer Tokens in .NET

Tags: asp.net-mvc, post, oauth-2.0, google-oauth

I'm building an MVC application in which a user must sign in with Google to provide offline access to their info.
I am getting the Access code via JavaScript from the View and sending it to controller.
From the controller I am making a POST request to the Google Api but i keep getting a Bad Request 400.

Has anyone managed to successfully implement this ?

```
        string baseUri = "https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v3/token/";
        string parCode = string.Format("code={0}",Code);
        string parSecret = "client_secret=******";
        string parId = "client_id=*******************";
        string parRedirect = "redirect_uri=https://localhost:44301";
        string postData = string.Format("{0}&{1}&{2}&{3}", parCode, parRedirect, parId, parSecret);
        Uri postUri = new Uri(baseUri);
        ASCIIEncoding encoding = new ASCIIEncoding ();
        byte[] data = encoding.GetBytes (postData);


        var  request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(baseUri);
        request.Method = "POST";
        request.ContentType = " application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
        request.ContentLength = postData.Length;
        HttpWebResponse response;

        Stream newStream = request.GetRequestStream();
        newStream.Write(data, 0, data.Length);
```

Comment: There is an MVC sample project here but its for using Google Calendar it may still give you some inspiration https://codereview.appspot.com/194980043/

Answer (score 0):

You're missing the `grant_type` parameter which should be set to `authorization_code`. You should also form-encode the individual parameter values. For the latter is convenient to use `NameValueCollection` as in:

```
NameValueCollection outgoingQueryString =  HttpUtility.ParseQueryString(String.Empty);
outgoingQueryString.Add("code", Code);
//...etc. for the other parameters
string postdata = outgoingQueryString.ToString();
```

Now `postData` will be properly encoded for usage in a form POST.

Comment: I have missed the grant_type parameter. I have fixed that, but what exactly is form-encoding please ?

Comment: I have added sample code that demonstrates forn encoding